# Inconsistent error reporting from Dart Editor regarding final fields

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Given the following class, Dart Editor (build 5549) gives me some conflicting feedback (per the comments in the constructor body):

```dart
class Example {
  final int foo;

  Example() :
    foo = 0
  {
    foo = 1; // 'cannot assign value to final variable "foo"'
    this.foo = 2; // ok
  }
}
```

Even more confusingly, it will happily generate equivalent (working) javascript for both lines. The situation seems to be the same with methods as it is with the constructor; this especially leads me to believe that it was intended to be disallowed in both cases.

The [Dart Style Guide](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/style-guide/) suggests using public final fields instead of private fields with public getters. I like this in theory, but non-trivial member construction can't really go into the initializer list.

Am I missing a valid reason for the former to be reported as an error while the latter is not? Or should I be filing a bug right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surely a bug in the JavaScript generator if you run the following in the Dart VM:

```dart
main() {
  new Example();
}

class Example {
  final int foo;

  Example() : foo = 0 {
    foo = 1;      // this fails in the dart vm
    this.foo = 2; // this also fails in the dart vm
  }
}
```

then it refuses to execute both the line **foo = 1** and **this.foo = 2**. This is consistent with the spec which requires (if I read it correctly) that final fields to be final in the constructor body.

Comment: Thanks. I hope I have the option of running Dartium on Windows soon. I went ahead and filed a bug: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=2213

Comment: @Neverender I believe Dartium should run on windows now http://dartwatch.com/index.php/2012/03/dartium-for-windows-binaries-now-available/